# Workaround for bug "W-3171561" introduced in Spring 15 release causing System.CalloutException

Tags: unit-test, callout, bug, platform-bug, gack

On February 2015 we have noticed some tests started failing suddenly on Production. We have opened a Salesforce support case and we were told that we are affected by [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2).

Recently that issue was marked as resolved but when I tried to run my simple test case scenario I got these errors again.

Simplified business logic test case scenario is following.

1. Create custom object Test_Object.
2. Create apex class and create a chatter group and use its id on line 10

   ```
   public class TestServices {
       @future(callout=true)
       public static void doSomeDummyCallOut() {
           Http h = new Http();
           HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
           req.setEndpoint('http://goo.gl'); 
           req.setMethod('GET');
           HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

           insert new FeedItem(Body='x' + res.getStatus(),ParentId='chatterGroupId');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a trigger on test object with code

   ```
   trigger TestTrigger on Test_Object__c (after insert, after update) {
       TestServices.doSomeDummyCallOut();
   }
   ```
4. Create test class TestTestTrigger with code

   ```
   @isTest
   private class TestTestTrigger {
       @isTest
       static void test1() {
           CollaborationGroup chatterGroup = new CollaborationGroup(Name = 'x', CollaborationType='Public');
           insert chatterGroup; 
           Test.startTest();
               Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponse());
               insert new Test_Object__c(Name = 'x');
           Test.stopTest();
       }
       @isTest
       static void test2() {
           Test.startTest();
               Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponse());
               Test_Object__c t = new Test_Object__c(Name = 'x');
               insert t;
               update t;
           Test.stopTest();
       }
       @isTest
       static void workAround() {
           Test.startTest();
           Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponse());
               insert new Test_Object__c(Name = 'x');
           Test.stopTest();
       } 
   }
   ```

Run the unit tests. Before Spring 15 Release all of these tests were executed successfully. After [including] Spring 15 release two of them are failing with "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" error.
[image]
[image]
Does anyone know about any good workaround for this issue?

Since commenting out business logic in test is not really a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have made a great discovery.

If we change API Version of Class which contains Callout to 28, the tests are not failing! It is amazing!
[image]
I believe I have tried the same two years ago and one year ago and this workaround didn't work then.

Comment: Good find!  One of the weird ways of SF i guess!!